# I have a problem with format a date in C#

Tags: c#, datetime, timezone, console-application

My pc time is in American form M/dd/yyyy h:mm tt so if I create a DateTime for example a DateTime.Now , that will be in a same form as my pc, but I need another format yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss , but I cannot change the DateTime.Now to another format , because I only can do this if the result will be a string , but I need a DateTime typed variable.

I tried to fix this like this:

```
string formattedDate = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
var time = DateTime.ParseExact(formattedDate, "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
Console.WriteLine(formattedDate);
Console.WriteLine(time);
```

but I got this output : [Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YPyQD.png)

Comment: The way you display a `DateTime` object is separate from the way the data is stored. You can display the same `DateTime` object in many ways. You can't think of a `DateTime` object as having a "format". That is only relevant when displaying.

Comment: If you could explain a bit more what you're trying to do, please. I'm guessing you're down-voted because of that. In your example parsing the date, you'd lose precision (i.e. milliseconds) and the [Kind](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.kind?view=net-7.0). Hope that helps.

Comment: I will try a translator , because I think my English might be the problem. So I have e.g. DateTime.Now and it gives me back e.g. 1/12/2023 8:58 PM , but I should not have the time in this format, but since the time is set this way on my computer , it is in this format. I would like the time to be in 2023/1/12 20:25 format , which I can do with .ToString() , but then I get back a string , but I need a DateTime , because I have to use it in my program , but I can't convert it back from string because then it will be in the wrong format again.

Comment: No, when you have `DateTime.Now`, you don't have a string at all - you have a [structure](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/struct) that encapsulates [a private field](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/DateTime.cs,155) that can be accessed via [`Ticks`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.datetime.ticks) and [`Kind`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.datetime.kind) properties.

Comment: That you see it as a string is a function of [`Console.Writeline`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.console.writeline) implicitly calling [`DateTime.ToString`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tostring) to show you a result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A culture can be specified for a thread.

```
    System.Globalization.CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US");
    Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now); // 1/13/2023 5:36:22 PM

    System.Globalization.CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
    Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now); // 01/13/2023 17:36:22
```